# CSS - border-width issue in Safari + Opera

Tags: css, safari, border

My top navigation is short by 2 pixels, but only in Safari and Opera.

http://orbitprint.com/canvas/

The ul has a box-shadow, so you can see that the last li is short. I can't figure out why for the life of me!

Is anyone able to throw some light on this for me please?

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Safari and Opera version and OS?

Comment: Safari 6.0.3, OS X 10.8.3

Comment: @Antony, I get what you're saying - but it's quite a lot of CSS. Surely it's better to inspect the rendered code from the actual document?

Comment: @dai.hop What about creating a Fiddle with the necessary code to replicate the problem?

Comment: @Terry, I'm happy to make one if that's what you want. It does seem like duplication of effort to me though! http://jsfiddle.net/6erVw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you use percentages in a pixel layout. Your Panel is 969px wide and 8Buttons with 12,5 percent (=> 969/8 = 121.125px) which have to fit into a natural numbered pixel. So the best would be to use display: table for the menu and display: table-cell for the buttons. That should split the given space as evenly as possible.

Comment: some browsers a round up, some down. That's why it is different.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've resized my panel so that it divides by 8 perfectly - it now renders correctly. You're a gentleman!